# How to calculate the number of message queue workers are needed?

Tags: system-design

In a system design interview question, I was given the QPS of incoming request and each of these request will need to be processed async so I have a message queue which dispatches these requests to workers.

What is the common way in industry to configure the number of workers for processing? Or how to calculate this number?